# Rails - Cocoon Gem - populating foreign key id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I am trying to use simple form with cocoon gem to nest children forms inside a parent class form.

I have models for proposal and pitch.

The associations are:

Proposal

```
  has_one :pitch, inverse_of: :proposal
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pitch, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Pitch

```
  belongs_to :proposal, inverse_of: :pitch
```

In my proposal form, I have:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :pitch do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
          <%= render 'pitches/pitch_fields', f: f %>

      <% end %>

      <%= link_to_add_association 'Pitch', f, :pitch, partial: 'pitches/pitch_fields' %>
```

In my proposal controller, I have:

```
def new
    @proposal = Proposal.new
    @proposal.build_pitch
    # authorize @proposal
  end

  def edit
    @proposal.build_pitch unless @proposal.pitch
  end


def proposal_params
      params.require(:proposal).permit(:title, :description, 

        pitch_attributes:       [:id, :problem, :solution, :remark, :_destroy ])
    end
```

pitches/_pitch_fields.html.erb has:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :problem, as: :text, 
          # :label =>  text_for_problem(current_user, @pitch.proposal), 
          :label =>  'What issue does this proposal address?', 
          :input_html => {:rows => 10} %>
      </div>
```

When I save all this and try it, the form loads and I can complete the form, but the foreign key for proposal_id saves as nil.

If I try to edit the form, I get an error that says:

```
Couldn't find Pitch with ID=5 for Proposal with ID=10
```

When I try:

```
pitch.errors.full_messages
NameError: undefined local variable or method `pitch' for main:Object
```

What do I need to do in order to force the proposal_id attribute in the pitch table to be set with the proposal id?

Comment: You get the error when saving the form, after edit?

Comment: yes - that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit weird, and imho a bug in rails, but the `link_to_add_association` will try to build a new `pitch` to be able to render it correctly. This will effectively *delete* the existing pitch.

So the solution is to add the option `force_non_association_create: true` on `link_to_add_association`. Or just drop the `link_to_add_association` altogether: why do you need it? You can have only one pitch, and you always create it if it does not exist?

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I'll give that a try now. I want to have the link button because if the proposal (which has_one pitch) is created without a pitch, then when the proposal is edited, I want the link to be able to create the pitch in the proposal edit form. Ill try your suggestion now.

Comment: But in your controller code you always add a pitch if does not exist, so... ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean I should add a build new tenor line to the new action in my organisation controller?

Comment: Confused!? I see no tenor mentioned anywhere, you already create a pitch in the controller, in both new and edit, and you still have a link-to-add-association for a pitch, just wondering if that makes sense. That is all.

Comment: Of course. Yes, you're right. thanks. Trying this now.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your _picthces/pitch_fields_ partial, but make sure it has a hidden field for `proposal_id`.

Also, add `proposal_id` to the `pitch_attributes` array in your `proposal_params` method.

If any other problems, put a breakpoint in the `edit` method of your controller and check what's in `proposal_params` vs what is set in the `@proposal` object.

Comment: Why do I need a hidden field? Other times I've used cocoon - i don't need a hidden field. The key difference between other uses of cocoon and this one is that proposal only has_one pitch (where every other case is a has_many relationship). I don't think using a hidden field is the answer, because it isn't necessary in every other use case.

Comment: Ahh, true the `fields_for` probably adds that on its own. But regardless, you'd need to permit it in your pitch_attributes array, right?

Comment: No. I don't need to do that in any other form that uses cocoon gem.  It gets updated without whitelisting the foreign key field in every other case that I use cocoon. The key difference in this case is the association is has_one instead of has_many but I can't figure out why that stops the foreign key id from being set.